# React Hooks : fetch data inside useEffect warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I am using react Hooks `useEffect` to fetch data from API in my component

```
props.getUserInfoAction() is an Action from redux dispatching user info
```

**Example**

```
useEffect(() => {
        props.getUserInfoAction();
      }, []);
```

works great, I can get my data but i found that i have a `warning` show up in my console.

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include
> it or remove the dependency array. However, 'props' will change when
> *any* prop changes, so the preferred fix is to destructure the 'props' object outside of the useEffect call and refer to those specific props
> inside useEffect  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

I tried to pass the `props` in the array but by doing that i get an infinite loop of API call.

```
useEffect(() => {
            props.getUserInfoAction();
          }, [props]);
```

Comment: The second argument as an `[]` empty array is meant for to run the useEffect when component first time mounts and unmounts. Is this what you want really?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `props.getUserInfoAction()` is an action you should instead of receiving already with a dispatch (from `connect` I assume) do this:

```
import {getuserInfoAction} from './actionCreators'
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux'

const Comp = () =>{
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() =>{
        dispatch(getUserInfoAction())
    },[dispatch])
}
```

Because even if you do this:

```
const {action} = props
```

Functions will always change between render calls.

Comment: yes i am doing that `from connect` but i don't want to remove that, is a question of code structure cause i am doing that for all my components thank you

Comment: i am using redux-thunk to dispatch actions , so using `useDispatch` inside the component  will not dispatch twice cause inside `getuserInfoAction` i am aleardy dispatching the data ?

Comment: useDispatch returns a memoized value to `dispatch` method, so it won't change between render's calls