# React hooks appends unwanted value with eslint-plugin-react-hooks@next

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `useEffect` hook in my component which call a Redux action to fetch some data.

```
useEffect(
 () => {
   props.getClientSummaryAction();
  },[]
);
```

When I go to save the file the linter does this.

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    props.getClientSummaryAction();
 }, [props] 
);
```

Which obviously send my component into an infinite loop as `getClientSummaryAction` fetches some data which updates the props.

I have used deconstruction like this and the linter updates the array.

```
  const { getClientSummaryAction } = props;

  useEffect(
    () => {
      getClientSummaryAction();
    },
    [getClientSummaryAction]
  );
```

Which I am fine with but it doesn't really make sense because `getClientSummaryAction` will obviously never be updated, its a function.

I just want to know why the linter is doing this and whether this is best practice.

Comment: Is not a problem, don't try to fix it, is the expected behaviour, you should think it twice again. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html

Comment: Because the linter is seeing that you are using a 'dependency' in your effect callback.

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia the way I am seeing it is that `[getClientSummaryAction]` indicates that if `getClientSummaryAction` changes run the effect again. But when would `getClientSummaryAction` change?

Comment: just when is received, the behaviour should be like ComponentDidMount in that case, isn't it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57097390/react-hooks-fetch-data-inside-useeffect-warning

Comment: Yeah I can see that I can use useDispatch too thanks

Comment: that works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not unwanted. You know for a fact that the dependency is not going to change, but `React` can possibly know that. The rule is pretty clear:

> Either pass an array containing all dependencies or don't pass anything to the second argument and let `React` keep track of changes.

Pass the second argument to `useEffect` is to tell React that you are in charge of hook's call. So when you don't pass a dependency that is included inside your effect `eslint` will see this as a possible memory leak and will warn you. [DO NOT disable the rule](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880) just continue to pass the dependency as you are already doing. May feel redundant but it's for the best.

Comment: Ok cool, I just felt it was redundant but I can see the in charge analogy very well.

Comment: It's a little unintuitive, but you eventually gets the gist